# Index out of bound python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm doing a small Python code to test a buy/sell strategy in a stock, and I'm getting this index out of bound error, BUT only with some values.

Error Log:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\envs\finance\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   3102             return self._engine.get_value(s, k,
-> 3103                                           tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))
   3104         except KeyError as e1:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: -1

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-81-3e66a7abf00d> in <module>()
     20 for i, s in enumerate(short):
     21     for j, l in enumerate(long):
---> 22         rets, sharpe = ma_strat( s, l)
     23         profit[i,j] = rets
     24         sharperat[i,j] = sharpe

<ipython-input-81-3e66a7abf00d> in ma_strat(short_, long_)
      9     datos['strategy'] = datos['ret'] * datos['pos'].shift(1)
     10     sh = np.sqrt(252) * (datos['strategy'].mean() / datos['strategy'].std())
---> 11     rets = datos['strategy'].cumsum()[-1]
     12     return rets, sh
     13 

~\Anaconda3\envs\finance\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    764         key = com._apply_if_callable(key, self)
    765         try:
--> 766             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
    767 
    768             if not is_scalar(result):

~\Anaconda3\envs\finance\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   3107 
   3108             try:
-> 3109                 return libindex.get_value_box(s, key)
   3110             except IndexError:
   3111                 raise

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.get_value_box()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.get_value_box()

IndexError: index out of bounds
```

If I set the linspace values to this works fine:

```
short = np.linspace(2, 4, 2, dtype=int)
long = np.linspace(10, 12, 2, dtype=int)
```

but if I Set the values to this: ( in the code below )
doesn't work. Shows Index out of bound error.

```
def ma_strat(short_, long_):
    datos['sh'] = ta.EMA(datos['Adj Close'].values, short_)
    datos['lg'] = ta.EMA(datos['Adj Close'].values, long_)
    datos.dropna(inplace=True)
    datos['pos'] = np.where(datos['sh']>datos['lg'], 1, 0)
    datos['ret'] = np.log(datos['Adj Close'] / datos['Adj Close'].shift(1))
    datos['strategy'] = datos['ret'] * datos['pos'].shift(1)
    sh = np.sqrt(252) * (datos['strategy'].mean() / datos['strategy'].std())
    rets = datos['strategy'].cumsum()[-1]
    return rets, sh

short = np.linspace(3, 13, 11, dtype=int)
print(short)
long = np.linspace(13, 23, 11, dtype=int)
print(long)
profit = np.zeros((len(short), len(long)))
sharperat = np.zeros((len(short), len(long)))

for i, s in enumerate(short):
    for j, l in enumerate(long):
        rets, sharpe = ma_strat( s, l)
        profit[i,j] = rets
        sharperat[i,j] = sharpe
```

Comment: Can you post a full traceback?

Comment: Could you post a simple working example that we can test?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `datos['strategy'].cumsum()[-1]` is returning pandas Series. Thats why the `[-1]` index may not be working.

Try `np.array(datos['strategy']).cumsum()[-1]`

Hope this helps

Comment: Can you paste the entire error log here. Would be more helpful. And just out of curiosity - is `ma_strat( s, l)` the same as `ma_strategy(short_, long_)`  ?

Comment: done, yes is the same, Mistake when paste the code.

Comment: First thing - Key error of -1 is because you are using cumsum()[-1] on a pandas series. That exception is leading to Index out of bound exception. Can you print the output of `type(datos['strategy'])` and also try using `rets = datos['strategy'].values.cumsum()[-1]` in your function.

Comment: output: <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

and if I change the line of code gives me this error:
IndexError: index -1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Comment: 1 thing is clear that its Pandas Series is not returning the output of [-1]. Can you add print output of `datos['strategy']`, `datos['strategy'].values` and `len(datos['strategy'])`. There could be a possibility that your series may have all NaN values

Comment: YES! they are all NaN

Comment: That&#39;s the root cause. Check why is your column returning NaN values , rectify and populate it with relevant values and then use the solution provided in answer.